# reading comment from excel using Apache POI

Tags: excel, apache-poi

I want to read the comment from an excel sheet.The below code works fine when I read the cell value but does not outputs the comment added to the same cell.

What is wrong with the code?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\421384\\Desktop\\excel.xlsx");
XSSFWorkbook wb=new XSSFWorkbook(f);
XSSFSheet sh = wb.getSheet("sheet1");
XSSFRow r = sh.getRow(0);
XSSFCell c = r.getCell(0);
CellType type =c.getCellTypeEnum();
System.out.println(c.getStringCellValue());
XSSFComment comment = c.getCellComment();
System.out.println(comment);
System.out.println(comment.toString());
```

**Console output:**

```
akash
org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFComment@0
org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFComment@0
```

Comment: Please use the API documentation of [XSSFComment](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFComment.html). Especially the [XSSFComment.getString()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFComment.html#getString()) will be useful for you.

Comment: Thanks Axel, `comment.getString()` is the method that works here.Thanks again.